# After low level formatting can Microsoft track previously pirated Windows installed on pc

Tags: windows-installation

I am getting call from Microsoft and they are forcing me to purchase so many licensed software but my budget is not that much. So they are asking for On-Site Audit (SAM Review).

So I did low level formatting of my all PC's and Installed Ubuntu. So can they track I installed pirated Windows XP earlier on these system or I need to change hardware..

After formatting on what parameter Microsoft Track earlier piracy:

1. By any Harddisk ID
2. By any Motherboard ID
3. By any IP Address

Please help me otherwise I have to borrow so much money for licensing fee.

Comment: Getting phone calls forcing you to purchase things does **NOT** sound like Microsoft's doing. Sounds much more like some scammers masquerading as Microsoft.

Comment: if you have formatted your drives, and installed opensource software, you could simply invite them to audit the facility, and show them that you don't have any MS software running. When in doubt about these kinds of things, its best to consult a lawyer.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe heard first person reports of MSFT doing that to small companies here in India.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: The call is a scam when you're an individual, but businesses with Volume License deals do get such calls. However, in those cases the Microsoft representative should have the contract details available.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they don't see any traces of their OS on your systems you should be ok. A format is more than enough. Keep Ubuntu installed and remove any Microsoft stickers your equipment may have.

Though you may have to replace the motherboard if they somehow manage to have a register of a pirated product linked to the motherboards' serial, but I think this will cost you more than buying the licences.

Comment: microsoft stickers indicate an install is legal. Makes no sense to remove them.

Comment: It may be unsettling for you to see machines with your brand running a different software, and the fact that they're forcing him to buy licences makes one think they lack some sense too.

Comment: In general, Microsoft does not have the right to inspect your PC running Ubuntu. Just showing it boots straight to Ubuntu without a boot menu option for Windows is proof that Microsoft has no legal rights relating to that PC.

Comment: Again, as the OP suggests, *right* means a little to them. Trust me, I live in Mexico and things like this happen, they'll try as hard as they can to make you buy a license (that includes pushing legal stuff too), one shouldn't let them have the minimum chance to have arguments on their side. I also remember having to remove the stickers on my system on a science fair (Intel ISEF preliminary) because my computer didn't have windows installed, only my Fedora installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they can ask for license fees if you really no longer have licensed software installed...